# In Python is there a way to find which object has a specific attribute?

Tags: python, class, object, search, attributes

For example, if I have:

```
class person:
    def __init__(self, name, age, address=None):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.address = address

person1 = person("Julie", 32)
person2 = person("Jack", 41)
person3 = person("John", 28)
```

I want to find what person is 32 of age.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are there any particular requirements? Otherwise, why not just loop it to get the person?

```
persons = [person1, person2, person3]
results = []

for p in persons:
    if p.age == 32:
        results.append(p)

for p in results:
    print(p.name, p.age)
```

Output:

```
Julie 32
```

Comment: Very new to python (and coding in general), I did not think of this. Thank you!

Comment: @Biochem, no worries. If you believe my solution works, could you please accept it so we can close this question?

Answer (score -2):

In Python(by default) the class variables are **public**.
So to find which Person's age is 32.
Follow the Code by Christopher. That answers your question

**Private Modifier in Python**

```
# program to illustrate private access modifier in a class 
  
class Student: 
     
     # private members 
     __name = None
     __roll = None
     __branch = None
  
     # constructor 
     def __init__(self, name, roll, branch):   
          self.__name = name 
          self.__roll = roll 
          self.__branch = branch
```

**Protected Modifier in Python**

```
# program to illustrate protected access modifier in a class 
class Student: 
     
     # protected data members 
     _name = None
     _roll = None
     _branch = None
     
     # constructor 
     def __init__(self, name, roll, branch):   
          self._name = name 
          self._roll = roll 
          self._branch = branch
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question and is, besides of that, completely wrong.

Comment: I don't see any evidence for your statement.